# Did Bach call for male countertenor for the Alto solo part for his cantatas / passion oratorios?

Tags: j-s-bach, baroque-period, performance-practice

I see a recent trend for countertenors to sing the alto parts for Bach's cantata / passion oratorios such as [Maarten Engeltjes](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maarten_Engeltjes) in [Magnificat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsUWG2axB3w&t=1174s) and [Tim Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Mead) in [St. Matthew Passion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwVW1ttVhuQ&t=826s).

Is this recent trend part of trying to be authentic, as those 2 performances used original instruments?  Did Bach call specifically for countertenor in his lifetime?

Comment: Well, we think of it today as "instead of a female alto," but his church choirs were entirely men and boys, so the real question is "adult countertenor or boy"? Although I'm a baroque musician, I'm ashamed to say I can't speak with much authority to this one. Here's [a relevant page](https://oslmusic.org/bach_posts/the-male-voice-and-bach-part-ii/) (see also its "part 1" on sopranos). Pull quote: "Using a countertenor to sing an alto part in Bach is as far from the composer’s intentions as using a woman for a soprano part."

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks.  Another quote: "In German church music from the Baroque, as women were forbidden in organ lofts and castrati were reserved for the opera house, alto parts were always sung by boys (possibly the older ones on the cusp of adolescence)."  Does it mean that for the cantatas & oratorios composed for church service the congregation never hear them performed with adult females singing the (sometimes) complicated solo parts?  How about soprano solo parts?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that's true. (See the [part 1](https://oslmusic.org/bach_posts/the-male-voice-and-bach/) about just how rare it is to find a boy who can handle them!

Comment: @AndyBonner average age of puberty was rather later then, though, so it was probably less rare in those days.

Comment: @AndyBonner I just read both articles thoroughly (great essays, BTW) and it looks like Bach preferred to render Soprano and Alto solo with proficient young boy voices, making it harder for us today as boys break their voices earlier and there are not that many virtuoso boys capable to meet Bach's musical demands.

Comment: @AndyBonner from your link: "Bach must have met with a few exceptional young alto singers at specific periods in time, though unfortunately history hasn’t retained their names. In 1726 for instance...."  As I was falling asleep last night, it occurred to me that this could have been one of Bach's sons, and indeed, his first son, Wilhelm Friedemann, was the right age to have been this alto, having been born on 22 November 1710.  I wonder whether we know if he was an alto, however; Johann Sebastian was apparently a soprano as a boy.

Comment: @AndyBonner The [1970 Harnoncourt recording with subsequent ones](https://www.bach-cantatas.com/Vocal/BWV244-Harnoncourt.htm) mentioned in the essay is available [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3X9rAxPyfc&list=OLAK5uy_mtu5L3v7SNPd2u57EHx9EhiJi0hy5d0ww) featuring anonymous boy soprano (ex. [Wiewohl mein Herz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmMcPFTtwKY&list=OLAK5uy_mtu5L3v7SNPd2u57EHx9EhiJi0hy5d0ww&index=19) and [Aus Liebe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3X9rAxPyfc&list=OLAK5uy_mtu5L3v7SNPd2u57EHx9EhiJi0hy5d0ww&index=68)) and countertenor Paul Esswood for alto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bach did not need to specifically call for countertenors, because at the time he was composing, it was a given that all parts were sung by men or boys (unless the piece was specifically composed for girl choir). Soprano and alto parts would be assigned to boys whose voices had not yet changed.

Bach was in Weimar from 1708 – 1717. The list of musicians in the court in 1714 – 1715 includes clearly and only male names for the higher-voices singers.

> Johann Philipp Weichardt ..... discant [i.e., high voice]
> Johann Christian Gerrmann .... discant
> Christian Gerhard Bernhardi .. alto
> (Wolff 158, Table 6.2)

Many of Bach's cantatas were written from 1723 – 1729 during his time directing the St. Thomas School's musical activities.

> Most of the vocal concertists were found among the *alumni* [emphasis original] assigned to the first choir, an elite group consisting of the best twelve to sixteen singers. Their entry ages as resident choral scholars varied, but they usually began as thirteen- or fourteen-year-old sopranos, invariably with prior singing experience in other Latin school choirs, and they stayed for maximum of eight years, usually two years per class. Because in the eighteenth century the change of voice occurred later than it does today, many of the boys could sing soprano for several more years. (Wolff 260)

---

Wolff, Christian. 2000. *Johann Sebastian Bach: The Learned Musician*. W.W. Norton & Company.

Comment: The question of boy vs falsettist seems to be quite heated, though.

Comment: @AndyBonner My understanding is that it was both, depending on the available singers.

Comment: So even though [the Magnificat manuscript](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/3/37/IMSLP436995-PMLP06399-Partitur.pdf) says "Soprano" and "Alto" they were sung by men / boys?  Even the solo (Recitative & Aria) parts?  Do we have a reference to a journal article / book such as the Bach Reader?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple the idea that "soprano" and "alto" imply female voices is completely anachronistic.  Note that none of this applies to Handel's oratorios, however.  For example, the first person to perform the role of King Solomon was a woman, [Caterina Galli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterina_Galli).  These are not liturgical works, of course.

Comment: "My understanding is that it was both, depending on the available singers": is that understanding based on any evidence, perhaps accounts of specific performers at specific performances?

Comment: @phoog "*... completely anachronistic*".  I see.

Answer (score 2):

Bach was a church musician with a certain budget and certain conditions he had to perform with.  That implies an all-male choir and typically male soloists, often adolescents.  "Did Bach call for" however is not a question about how the performances were usually made but what Bach did envision or at least would have wanted.

Bach himself did in a number of pieces just ignore performance constraints and expected best-fit replacements.  There was his Great Catholic Mass in B minor where a "historically informed practice" would demand it not be performed as all, written in an old rite no longer performed in Catholic churches and certainly not in Protestant ones.  There are four-part fugues for solo violin and other works where it takes a lot of performer's judiciousness to arrive at an execution.

A male countertenor would certainly be period-adequate for a Bach performance, but Bach did not employ them ironically (like one would a drag queen).  So it's more doing a favor to current audiences who want to imagine reexperiencing what the old audiences witnessed than following Bach's vision in a particularly validated manner.

Comment: Great point distinguishing Bach's vision vs. performance limitation.  Given the choice in modern times, without "boys only" church rule, and with a choice of 3 color of adult female (soprano,mezzo or alto), adult male countertenor or (God forbid) male soprano castrati, can we infer from surviving letters, scribbles in manuscript, compositional characteristics or inherent artistic tonality/balance, which one Bach would have chosen?

Comment: What a composer "would do" today is a fraught (though sometimes worthwhile) exercise—would Mozart just be David Bowie? This gets into some of the points that Richard Taruskin likes to make about false "authenticity": the goal of "historically-inspired performance practice" isn't to stage some re-enactment of a historical event. I always say I do baroque performance practice not because it's more "right" but because it's more fun.

Comment: @AndyBonner "the goal...isn't to stage some re-enactment": sometimes it is, but it is indeed good to remember that it doesn't have to be. I do think that it is more right, but much of that is subjective--and accordeonist Richard Galliano's Bach album is a pleasure to listen to. That's more "right" in my view than some period instrument ensembles I've heard in recent years. Still, the movement came from a desire to get closer to the conditions under which the music was written, and the impossibility of achieving authenticity shouldn't be an excuse for ceasing to be mindful of it.

Comment: @AndyBonner I also wonder whether you're familiar with St. Luke's output. They're one of only two orchestras I know playing on modern instruments that consistently realize stylistic performances of baroque music (in my HIP-biased opinion, of course), the other being [The Knights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Knights_(orchestra)). Modern-instrument performances have definitely been influenced by the baroque specialists (Metropolitan Opera playing Handel, for example). The "more fun" line is a great way to introduce these ideas; I have been using "sounds better," but maybe I'll switch.

Comment: @phoog 1) This should probably move to chat, or maybe it's own question about "why should I HIP?", but, 2) I should probably let Taruskin speak for himself—I *think* I was thinking of [this](http://www.posgrado.unam.mx/musica/lecturas/historiaInterpretacion/JSTOR/Taruskin-Authenticity.pdf)? Though he rehearses the same points in a lot of places. As applicable in this question, I imagine he would say that if the choice is mounting a *bad* production with children because it's what Bach did vs doing it *well* with countertenors, he would attack the first as false authenticity. ...

Comment: @phoog ... (ditto for failing to take musical risks just because they can't be documented, like the conductor who would allow no ornaments without proof of precedent.) On choosing HIP, my analogy for audiences is: Imagine you live in a future in which, for whatever reason, no one plays anything but synthesizers. And that future has never stopped loving the music of the Beatles, but plays it only in New-Wave synthy style. ...

Comment: @phoog ... They argue "Today's synths are so much more versatile! So much more capable! I'm sure they would have used them if they'd had them. Why should I do this fabulous music the disservice of playing it on a less-evolved instrument?" And there's nothing wrong with them providing this interpretation, just like Glenn Gould's Bach has a right to exist alongside Switched-On. But you could argue that you'll never really *understand* the Beatles' music until you hear it played on the instruments it was written for, guitars and acoustic drums, even preferably tube amps.

Comment: The B-minor mass was composed for the Dresden court of the king (elector) of Saxony, who was a Catholic.